# Summarize a data frame based on consecutive rows with repeated values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
pos<- c(67,125,158,195,235,458,499,526,785,912,999,1525)
v_1<-c("j","c","v","r","s","q","r","r","s","t","u","v")
v_2<-c("c","t","v","r","s","q","r","w","c","c","o","v")
v_3<-c("z","c","v","r","s","q","r","w","c","b","p","v")
v_4<-c("x","w","z","z","s","q","r","w","c","o","t","v")
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(pos,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4))
```

In this dataframe it is possible to find the same letters among the different columns in **consecutive rows**. I need to obtain a separate data frame with the values of the variable "pos" for consecutive rows with shared letters, as can be seen in the figure:
[image]

In this figure even though all the columns have the same letter in pos 1525, this row isn’t included since it’s not  consecutive with another row with repeated letters.

Comment: Unclear to me what you mean with "consecutive row". For example, the letter "C" is found in row 2 and 9, which are not consecutive. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Chris! Imean, the shared letters among the different columns must be in consecutive rows. For example, in the last row all the columns have the same letter ("v") but since is not consecutive with the rest of the shared letters, v, must be not taken in consideration.

Comment: Put another way, you want to look at rows where a column has the same value as at least one other column, AND that’s the case for that column for at least two consecutive rows, even if the shared value isn’t the same from one row to the next. Do I have that right, or have I just muddled things further?

Comment: Correct! Thanks a lot for your help Zephryl! Best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using tidyr and dplyr:

1. After pivoting to long, use `dplyr::add_count()` to find repeated values within each `pos`;
2. Within each `v`, find consecutive rows with repeated values, defined as: >1 repeat *and* >1 repeat in either preceding or following row;
3. Create a column containing `pos` for consecutive rows and `NA` otherwise;
4. Take the minimum and maximum to get `start` and `end` for each `v`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(!pos, names_to = "v") %>%
  add_count(pos, value) %>%
  group_by(v) %>%
  mutate(consec = ifelse(
    n > 1 & (lag(n) > 1 | lead(n) > 1),
    pos,
    NA
  )) %>%
  summarize(
    start = min(consec, na.rm = TRUE),
    end = max(consec, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  v     start end  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 v_1   125   499  
2 v_2   158   785  
3 v_3   125   785  
4 v_4   235   785
```

Note, not sure if/how you want to handle if there is more than one set of consecutive rows, so this solution doesn’t address that.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right. I may find that case. But I would like to try to addp it by myself. I'm going step by step. However, I might not being able to solve it, if that's the case, can I ask you? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, feel free to comment here if needed.